# For Loop in Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I am new to shell scripting, and I've recently encountered something I didn't comprehend.

What is the difference between these two scripts:

Script 1:

```
COLORS="RED YELLOW GREEN"
for i in $COLORS
do
echo $i
done
```

Script 2:

```
for i in "RED YELLOW GREEN"
do
echo $i
done
```

From my perspective, they should have the same output, but they don't.
Output:

Script 1:

```
RED
YELLOW
GREEN
```

Script 2:

```
RED YELLOW GREEN
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes down to quoting and variable expansion rules.

After variable expansion, the quotes in the first example are gone and this is equivalent to a loop over 3 elements:

```bash
for i in RED YELLOW GREEN
do
echo $i
done
```

whereas the second example is a loop over one element that happens to be a string containing spaces:

```bash
for i in "RED YELLOW GREEN"
do
echo $i
done
```

If you want to get the second behavior while using a variable, you need to add a level of quoting around the variable expansion, ie:

```bash
COLORS="RED YELLOW GREEN"
for i in "$COLORS"
do
echo $i
done
```